# Optimizing GeoJSON MongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb, geojson, mongoengine

I have some polygons stored in GeoJSON in my mongoDB.

The client sends a list of boxes to load (the boxes are cells of a regular grid).

The normal way to retrieve them is to make a GeoJSON query with each box, but it is slow when I have many boxes.

I do not want to retrieve duplicates (polygons which lie on two cells are returned twice), so I make a list of retrieved polygons *pks* to ignore them in the next queries.

Given:

```
box = [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ]  // the box to load
pks = [ ObjectId("54cf535cfe022e01ab4932f5"), ObjectId("54cf535cfe022e01ab4932f6") ] // the list of polygons already retrieved
```

With mongoDB I would have something like this:

```
for box in boxes:
    db.places.find( { points: 
        { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { type: "Polygon" ,  coordinates: box } } },
        { _id: { $nin: pks } } 
    } )
```

I use MongoEngine, so I have the following:

```
pks = []
for box in boxes:
   p = Polygon.objects(points__geo_intersects=box, pk__nin=pks)
   if len(p)>0:       
      pks += p.scalar("id")
```

I have three questions:

**1. Is there a more efficient way to query the polygons with this method?**

**2. Would it be faster to use a Cell object containing the list of reference of polygons which lie on the cell?**

In MongoEngine I would have the following model:

```
class Cell(Document):
    x = DecimalField()
    y = DecimalField()
    polygons = ListField(ReferenceField('Polygon'))

    meta = {
        'indexes': [[ ("x", 1), ("y", 1) ]]
    }
```

The list of boxes to load would be the coordinates corresponding to the cells to load.

This would give with MongoEngine:

```
polygons = {}

for b in boxes:
    cell = Cell.objects.get(x=b['x'], y=b['y'])

    for polygon in cell.polygons:
        if not polygons.has_key(polygon.pk):
            polygons[polygon.pk] = polygon.to_json()
```

**3. Is there a more efficient way to query the polygons with this method?** (I think I should use [select_related()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.select_related), and maybe it is possible to filter the polygons directly in the mongoDB query to avoid retrieving duplicates)

Comment: I just made a benchmark: it took 2.03 seconds to retrieve my polygons with the first method, and 0.65 seconds with the second method.

Comment: Hum... Actually I just found out that the difference probably comes from `pk__nin=pks` which takes longer. Now I have faster results with the first method... I will further investigate this after lunch...

Answer (score 0):

After making a few benchmarks, I can answer my own questions: it is not noticeably faster to use an intermediate object such as `Cell`.

However, using a list of primary keys in the query, like this:

```
pks = []
for box in boxes:
   p = Polygon.objects(points__geo_intersects=box, pk__nin=pks)
   if len(p)>0:       
      pks += p.scalar("id")
```

is much slower than using a dictionary to ignore duplicates, like this:

```
polygons = {}
for box in boxes:
   p = Polygon.objects(points__geo_intersects=box)
   for polygon in p:
      if not polygons.has_key(polygon.pk):
          polygons[polygon.pk] = polygon.to_json()
```